# How to set default SIM for data and SMS programatically in android

Tags: java, android, dual-sim

I have been working on app run on `android 7.0` or above. 
It is a **system** app.

How can i set default SIM for `data connections` and sending `SMS` using android java.

I have try using `SubscriptionManager` class to get the current subscriptions, but not able to set any plan.

Whenever i reinsert the SIM in device, Settings for default sim for sending SMS and data reset to `selection required`. I want it to be set to SIM in slot 1 by default whenever my app runs.